# access denied after setting up superuser

Tags: sharepoint-server, access-denied, object-cache

I keep getting "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you." after I ran

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity “<WebApplication>”

$wa.Properties[“portalsuperuseraccount”] = “<SuperUser>”

$wa.Properties[“portalsuperreaderaccount”] = “<SuperReader>”

$wa.Update()
```

I tried to undo by saying:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication "URL"

$wa.Properties.Remove("<SuperUser>")

$wa.Properties.Remove("<SuperReader>")

$wa.Update()
```

but i keep getting access denied

Comment: fow which user you are getting this error message? for all? Have you tried IIS reset, you can set permission with Web Application Policy to, for FULL READ.

Comment: from site collection administrator.... i tried several IIS resets and even restart of server- what do you mean "you can set permission with Web Application Policy to, for FULL READ" ? where?

Comment: check in Central Administration > Application Management > Site Collection Administrators if there is set proper account. You can set FULL READ or FULL control (User Policy) in Web Application panel, select web application and in ribbon on right side is User Policy

Comment: all that is set but still get the access denied.

Comment: hm this is odd.. any different account works?

Comment: the web application where i had set the super user is not accessible by anyone..........

Comment: what? this should not affect this. I dont know what to recommend now.

Answer (score 1):

setting up the Object cache is 2 steps process:

1. add the superuser and super reader in the Policy of Web applications
2. Run powershell script to set the super user and super reader in web application's property.
3. Lastly, perform the IIS reset farm wide ( on all server).

Things to check:

- make sure you completed above steps.
- used the right accounts on both steps.
- Most Important, Make Sure when you run the powershell, add the proper claims for the users. I am sure you are using the claims enabled web application.

check this gallery code, may be help you to fix the issue.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2016-Object-888ce77f